# Using JQWidgets jqxListMenu to log when a user clicks a menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, widget

This is my **first** question on Stack Overflow and I am extremely new to html/javascript/jquery, so feel free to make suggestions.

I am using [JQWidgets, jqxListMenu specifically](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxlistmenu/index.htm#demos/jqxlistmenu/defaultfunctionality.htm). I like this menu a lot, but I cannot find how to console.log() the text from each click a user makes in their provided [API](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxlistmenu/index.htm#demos/jqxlistmenu/defaultfunctionality.htm). I did get the console to log one click, but not every click.  How do I log each of my menu item's specific text on every click? I need this text to store it to our database. Thank you!

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/scripts/demos.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxlistmenu.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#list').jqxListMenu({ width: '300px', enableScrolling: false, showHeader: true, showBackButton: true, showFilter: false });
    $("#list").on('click', function (event) {
      var my_string = $("#list").text();
      console.log("item was clicked");
      console.log(my_string);
      $('#my_results').text( my_string );
    });

  });
  </script>

</head>
<body class='default'>

  <ul id="list" data-role="listmenu">
    <li>item 1
      <ul data-role="listmenu">
        <li>item 1-1
        </li>
        <li>item 1-2
          <ul data-role="listmenu">
            <li>item 1-2-1</li>
            <li>item 1-2-2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>item 2
    </li>
  </ul>

  <p id="my_results">results here </p>

</body>
</html>
```